# Chinese remainder theorem - simple case

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

> A boy playing with a pile of cubic blocks finds that he is short of $5$ blocks to make a solid whose base is $4\times 4$ square. Also he finds that if he makes a solid whose base is a $5\times 5$ square, he is left with an extra block. If the boy manages to make a solid where the base is a $3\times 7$ rectangle using all the available blocks, find the least number of blocks the boy mush have had.

I have solved this problem but I want to know what its answer is? My answer is 651

Comment: This is equivalent to solving the system\begin{cases}x\equiv -5\mod{16}\\x\equiv1\mod{25}\\x\equiv0\mod{21}\end{cases}which has the solution$$x=651+8400k\qquad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$thus you are correct.

Comment: Please choose a more informative title.

Comment: Thank for your answer

Comment: @Dake I edited the title and tags to be more informative. If you want to know more about how to solve such questions in general see the [WikipediaArticle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: Thank for your information

Answer (score 1):

As already stated and explained in the comments, you answer is correct. You can get this result in [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ChineseRemainder%5B%28-5%2C1%2C0%29%2C%2816%2C25%2C21%29%5D) using `ChineseRemainder[(-5,1,0),(16,25,21)]`.